# Android - notifying message becoming online

Tags: android, android-notifications

Being a  beginner i have just learnt how to create a notification for android apps. now the thing is, i am trying to notify some message that can only be known if my friends become online with their device through my apps. so what should i now do or need to learn for the task ? please guide me cordially. thank you.

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value of online_friends. If `online_friends=true`, set the `notification_trigger=true`

Comment: ok. and for that will i have to make any server ? i am quite a beginner so many of the thing about android are new to me.

Comment: You could use the server that you're also using to handle logins for your apps...